# Type safety and scoping in OptionsPattern arguments

Tags: options, optional-arguments

I am new to `OptionsPattern`. Consider

```
ClearAll[r`f, n];
r`f[x1_, OptionsPattern[{n -> 100}]] := Module[{N},
  N = OptionValue@n;
  Print@{x1, OptionValue@n};
  ]
r`f[99, n -> "typeViolator!"]
(*{99,typeViolator!}*)
```

A simple function `r'f` is defined with an option `n`of default value `100`. `n` is meant to be an int.

1. As seen in the example, during invocation, `n` can be set to any type. How to ensure type safety while defining `OptionsPattern`? (something like  `n_Integer`?)
2. One had to `ClearAll[n]` before using it within OptionsPattern. Is there a way to avoid this i.e some better way to writing OptionsPattern without worrying about pre-definitions of its args?
3. Note that my module speciically makes available `n`, as `N`. (Yes, it hides the in-built function `N`, but assume that in the present scenario, variable names like N,D,I etc are necessary within the module and don't lead to code conflicts). I was forced to do this as using

```
r`f[...,OptionsPattern[N->100,...]]:=Module[{N},
                       ^                     ^
                       |                     |
                       1                     2
OptionValue@N    

]
```

causes collision between the shown positions 1 and 2 rendering `OptionValue@N`  useless. Also note that re-writing `OptionsPattern@N` within the module every time isn't feasible.
How does one define an OptionsPattern resembling `OptionsPattern[{N_Integer->4,D_Integer->4}]` while keeping all this and the above questions in mind ?

All clarifications are appreciated.

Comment: `f[x_, opts: OptionsPattern[]] /; checkOpts[opts] := Module[..]`? `f[x_, opts: OptionsPattern[]] := With[{optvals = processOpts[opts]}, Module[..] /; FreeQ[optvals, $Failed]]`? (Here, `processOpts` might construct an association of option values, so that `optvals@n` would yield the value.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider this alternative that more easily enforces type on `n` using two alternative definitions, the first one with the integer type, the second "default" one when n is not an integer, essentially similar to an error handler. You could also omit the second one and `` r`f `` would simply not evaluate when there is a type mismatch.

```
ClearAll[r`f, n];
r`f[x1_, n_Integer: 100] := {x1, n}
r`f[x1_, n_] := "mismatched option type!"
```

Let's try explicit values for both parameters:

```
r`f[3, 2]                  (* Out: {3, 2} *)
```

Now let's use the default value for `n`:

```
r`f[3]                     (* Out: {3, 100} *)
```

And finally a mismatch:

```
r`f[99, "typeViolator!"]   (* Out: "mismatched option type!" *)
```

Comment: this doesn't help...though thanks for illustrating overloading. The problem is I am using 10's of function arguments and really do want to redefine most into Options. Writing multiple overloaded forms for these many arguments isn't really practical

Comment: @lineage I understand. However, as far as I know you may be forced to explicitly type-check those option values within your implementation function. Automated "type-checking" would be the main advantage of the multiple-definition approach.